# Происхождение слов «галерея» и «галера»

Tags: этимология

Одного ли корня слова «галерея» (архит.), «галерка» (театр.), «галера» (мор.)? Если да, то как можно истолковать значение этого корня?

Answer (score 2):

1) Одинаковый исторический корень имеют слова ***галерея*** и ***галёрка***, хотя  значение корня  определяется **неоднозначно:**

**Из современного словаря:**

ГАЛЕРЕЯ, -и; ж. [итал. galleria] 1. Длинное и узкое помещение, проход, коридор, соединяющий части здания или разные здания; длинный балкон вдоль здания.

**Этимологический словарь Цыганенко**

http://www.slovorod.ru/etym-cyganenko/cyg-g.htm

ГАЛЕРЕЯ
<**длинный узкий крытый проход** между зданиями>,'<худож. музей>.
Заимствовано, вероятно, из франц. яз. в I пол. XVIII в. Полагают, что франц. galerie имеет **первонач. знач. <крытый ход>, <покрытие>.**
По этимол. оно связано с лат. galerum (galenis) <шапка>, <парик> - тоже свое- го рода <покрытие>.
Корень **galer-** отмечается в названии стар. гребного суд- на **галера.** На таких судах существовал **крытый ход**, где сидели прикован- ные к веслам гребцы.

Другие считают, что франц. galerie из итал. gallerie <галерея>, которое восходит к галльск. **galer <веселиться, развлекаться>** (ср. ст.-франц. gale <радость>, откуда соврем, франц. gala <празднество>), Следоват., **галерея - первонач. <место для прогулок и развлечений>**, <место, где гуляют во время дождя> > <помост с перилами>, <навес со скамьями>; в театре - <верхний ярус>, с ним связано разг. **галёрка.**
ГАЛЁРКА.

**Из словаря Черных**

В русском языке слово ***галлерия*** отмечено в 1711 году как архитектурный элемент во внутреннем убранстве дома, но уже в словаре 1831 года **галерия** — это верхний ярус в театре. У Пушкина в 1830 году — вариант галлерея (театр.)

**Из слова Фасмера**

стар. галерия, у Петра I (1705 г.), также галария; см. Смирнов 79; Христиани 45. По мнению первого, **из нем. Galerie или франц. galerie.** Предположение о заимствовании через польск. galeria (Христиани) не объясняет места ударения русск. слова.

2) Слово ***галера*** также может быть родственным по отношению к слову ***галерея***, но может иметь и **собственное происхождение.**

https://galea-galley.livejournal.com/9233.html

Варианты:

а) Галея и галера. Название судна ***галея***, по-видимому, произошло от греческого galeē — кошка, куница. Это быстрое и увертливое суденышко средних размеров.

б) ***Галера*** — слово чисто греческое, хотя 
в античности неизвестное. Его пустил в оборот, скорее 
всего, какой-нибудь византийский поэт, соединив 
***gals, galos*** («соль» — так Гомер метонимически 
именовал море) и ***eretmon*** (весло) либо ***eres*** (ряд весел).

Comment: Поддержал ответ. Отмечу только, что версия Цыганенко об этимологической связи галеры и галереи не поддерживается другими словарями и выглядит сомнительно. Вообще, в этом словаре находили грубые ошибки и я ему доверяю меньше. Ну и про галёрку хочу дополнить, что это не просто верхний ярус, но и самые дешёвые места, что важно.

Comment: Возможно, словарь Цыганенко не очень авторитетный, но там хотя бы версии нашлись. А в других словарях вообще ничего нет, даже у Черных, который любит обозначать и.-е корни. Вот еще попался материал из этимологического орфографического словаря: возможно, восходит к ср.-лат. galeria от др.-евр. galil  - всякая местность.

Comment: Галерея  это крупная архитектурная форма. Ее миниатюрное подобие, расположенное в пределах зрительного зала могло получить название (в русском языке) «галерейка», но укоренилась форма «галерка». Пренебрежительный тон легко объяснить тем, что на галерке находятся самые удаленные от сцены, едва пригодные для просмотра представлений, зрительские места.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, в словаре у Черных  есть такое замечание: пренебреж. "галёрка" встречается уже в произведениях 80-х годов XIX века, например у Чехова в рассказе "Нищий".